# Lisp without a Garbage Collector for low level programming

Tags: garbage-collection, lisp

Is there a dialect of Lisp which has Lisp semantics and low level manipulation of C? Something like retrieving an arbitrary memory address (either virtual or physical memory) and do something with it; pointer to hardware device...

For example:

```
(defvar a '(1 2 3 4)) ;; I have a list
(defvar b (cdr a)) ;; b is the cdr of a. But I want b to
                   ;;  actually refer to the tail of a
(setf b '(4 5 6)) ;; b now has new value, but a remains unchanged
```

What I want is to use Lisp to express low level problems. For example, how do I control individual bytes and bits when running Lisp on bare metal? In C, I can get a pointer and perform pointer arithmetic to point to anywhere I want in a memory space (virtual or physical). Pointer can also point to devices and arbitrary defined addresses by hardware designer.

Why do I need this? Well, I want to learn how to use Lisp with low level programming. In the long run, I want to write a simple OS for learning, but in Lisp. I will write one in C as well for initial understandings, but if I can only write in C, how can I be sure and say I understand how to implement an OS? I think I only truly understand how to implement an OS if I can write it in other language than C to make sure.

I don't want to write something like C core for the OS and Lisp for everything else.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. GC and low-level memory manipulation can co-exist.
Most Common Lisp implementations can do that. See the chapter about FFI in the respective manuals. See also implementations like ECL which can easily be embedded into C programs.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I edited the question to make it clear. Is there any other solution rather than relying on C and host OS for low level operations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, most Lisp implementations can do that. Common Lisp already has all kinds of bit calculation functions. All implementations provide interfaces to low-level operations.

You can write web servers, compilers, window managers, etc. in Lisp. Many Lisp systems are written in Lisp and thus need primitives to write/read to/from memory.

You just need to take some Lisp implementation and read the manual. It's all documented.

For example see the portability layer CFFI (Common Foreign Function Interface), the chapter on [pointers](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/Pointers.html#Pointers). CFFI works on top of several Common Lisp implementations.

Answer (score 7):

You may want to look at PreScheme:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.3.4031

> Pre-Scheme is a statically typed dialect of Scheme that gives the programmer the efficiency and lowlevel machine access of C while retaining many of the desirable features of Scheme. The PreScheme compiler makes use of type inference, partial evaluation and Scheme and Lisp compiler technology to compile the problematic features of Scheme, such as closures, into C code without significant run-time overhead. Use of such features in Pre-Scheme programs is restricted to those cases that can be compiled into efficient code. Type reconstruction is done using a modified Hindley/Milner algorithm that allows overloaded user-defined functions. All top-level forms in Pre-Scheme programs are evaluated at compile time, which gives the user additional control over the compiler's partial evaluation of a program. Pre-Scheme has been implemented and used to write a byte-code interpeter and associated support code for a complete Scheme implementation

I think Scheme48 still uses PreScheme in its implementation: http://s48.org/

Answer (score 4):

There was an old project which you might be interested to look through:

> Introduction
>
> The Movitz system aspires to be an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp
>   that targets the ubiquitous x86 PC architecture "on the metal". That
>   is, running without any operating system or other form of software
>   environment. Movitz is a development platform for operating system
>   kernels, embedded, and single-purpose applications. There can
>   potentially be several completely different operating systems built
>   using Movitz.

[Movitz: a Common Lisp x86 development platform](http://common-lisp.net/project/movitz/)

Answer (score 3):

You either create or alter an existing Lisp language with the low lever stuff and API you need to run LISP without a kernel or userland and cross compile that to a blob that is not linked to anything (static). SBCL can be bootstrapped with an alien CL implementation and even cross compile itself so if you want CL i would have started reading the code and articles about SBCL as well as operating system design.

How you go from there depends on what you want it to be. The running LISP can in theory have all the resources and you can make all your applications and support in there. You even have a garbage collector for the lowest level of your OS :)

You would eventually need a way to make common applications and device drivers easy to port. That way you can sail on others effort. Imagine if you needed to write your own browser or nvidia driver from scratch..

Comment: Thanks. I think I will need to have my own implementation without dependencies on host OS and bootstrap SBCL. Currently, my knowledge about OS is mainly Linux. My goal is to write a simple OS with Lisp to make CL on bare metal happens; I will deal with legacy stuffs later. Long way to go though.

Comment: @Amumu My private project is changing my (working) [LISP interpreter for Brainf*ck](http://sylwester.no/zozotez/) to be a compiled and lexically scoped rather than interpreted and dynamicly scoped. I think your project might be more complex and I estimate I'll use several years to get something self hosting.